# Help with differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I have a practice question..
I am reading material from a calculus book, and I am studying derivatives and differentiation with functions. One of the questions on a practice sheet I have is similar to this;
$$f(x) = 4x^2 + 2x - 4$$ at $x = -3$

and the answer should be in a $f ' (x)$ and $f' (-3)$ format.

I haven't come across any problems in this specific format (As far as I am aware) in the book; What steps do I take to solve it?

This is where I am so far;

## $4(x+h)^2 + 2(x+h) - 4 - (4x^2 - 2x + 4) / h $

## 4 (x^2 + 2xh + h^2) + 2x + 2h - 4 - (4x^2 - 2x + 4)/h

$4x^2 + 8xh + 4h^2 + 2x + 2h - 4 - 4x^2 - 2x + 4/h$

Am I on the right track? If so how do I finish it? as I mentioned the answer is in the format
$f'(x) = .....; f'(-3) =.......$

If not what are the correct steps? This is a sample problem I made up in a similar format to my actual questions so please feel free to answer as this is not a question from my homework.

Thank you very much

Comment: $$f(x)=4x^2+2x-4\\
f^{'}(x)=8x+2\\
f^{'}(-3)=-22$$

Comment: That is great thank you! I understand the 8x+2..but how did you get f '(-3) = 22? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Substitute $x=-3$ in $8x+2$.

Answer (score 1):

From your last step: (8xh + 4h^2 + 2h)/h = 8x + 2 + 4h ---> 8x + 2 as h ---> 0

Comment: Makes more sense now thank you! Just still wondering how the f'(-3) =... comes into play

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{h}$

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h-3)- f(-3)}{h}$

This is all good. You are on the right track. But the whole second bolded expression is divided by h, not just the last bit.

Keep simplifying by cancelling redundant terms.